# Exposing a class with a constructor that has an array argument with Boost Python

Tags: python, c++, class, boost, constructor

I am trying to export a class using Boost Python that looks like this:

```
struct bool_array
{
    bool_array(bool constructor_bool[7])
    {
        for(unsigned int i=0; i < 7; i++)
            bools[i] = constructor_bool[i];
    }

    bool bools[7];
};
```

I want to expose the constructor as well, using the following Boost code:

```
class_<bool_array>("bool_array", init<bool*>())
    .def_readwrite("bools", &bool_array::bools)
;
```

The problem is I am getting this compiler error:

```
error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'const bool [7]' to 'bool [7]'
```

I have also tried

```
init<bool[7]>
```

and

```
init<bool[]>
```

to no avail.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I have been unable to figure out what I need to do to expose this class.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While banging my head on this, I learned that boost-python doesn't support direct exposure of C-style arrays. Instead, I opted to use a vector:

```
struct bool_array
{
    bool_array(std::vector<bool> constructor_bool)
    {
        for(unsigned int i=0; i < 7; i++)
            bools.push_back(constructor_bool[i]);
    }

     std::vector<bool> bools;
};
```

With the following boost-python wrapper:

```
typedef std::vector<bool> BoolVector;
bp::class_<BoolVector>("BoolVector")
    .def(bp::vector_indexing_suite<BoolVector>())
;

bp::class_<bool_array>("bool_array", bp::init<std::vector<bool>>())
    .def_readwrite("bools", &bool_array::bools)
;
```